# method save - get current ID

Tags: php, symfony1

```
class News extends BaseNews
{
    public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null)
    {
      $this->setUserId($this->getAttribute('user_id'));

      return parent::save($conn);
    }
}
```

How can i get here current save News ID? I would like add this for session, but i dont know how can i get this?

Comment: what dose 'here current save News ID' means?

Comment: i add new News. I would like get ID this news.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used symfony but as far as I understand you, you want something like this:

```
class News extends BaseNews
{
    public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null)
    {
      $this->setUserId($this->getAttribute('user_id'));
      $result = parent::save($conn);

      echo $this->getId(); // Your news Id

      return $result;
    }
}
```